# UK Tier 5 Youth Moblity visa never used and is expired, what can I do ?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, canada

I'm a Canadian citizen and got a Tier 5 Youth Moblity visa 2 years ago as I thought I would need it but a last minute change made me stay in Canada. This means my visa is no longer valid and has expired since I never used it. Now I want to go to the UK and am still eligible for the Tier5 visa, can I still get this Tier 5 UK visa again since I never used and do I need to pay again ?

Comment: The Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa information at https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility says that as a Youth Mobility Visa holder you may not "extend your stay." From this, it's logical to conclude that reinstating your now-expired visa will not succeed. However, the same page says you're not eligible to apply if you've previously been physically in the UK on a Youth Mobility Visa. Since you haven't been in the UK on a YMV, if you meet the other requirements you can apply again. Whether a new, second visa will be granted to you is up to UKVI.